# Sorting references in alphabetical order but with misc entries at the end

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, sorting

I am using

```
\bibliographystyle{plain} 
\bibliography{my_bibliography}
```

to sort the references in my document alphabetically. In this context, the misc entries that have no author appear all the way at the beginning although I would prefer them to appear at the very end. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a non-empty `key` field -- with a string value that starts with `ZZ` -- to the entries which don't have an `author` (or `editor`) field. That way, these entries will be placed *after* all other entries in the sorted bibliography. (Note that the `key` *field* is separate from the entry's key, which is the label by which it is `\cite`d.)

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{my_bibliography.bib}
@misc{a,author="A. Author",title="Thoughts",year=2001}
@misc{b,key="ZZ1",title="Further thoughts",year=2001}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{my_bibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! That seems to work but somehow if two misc entries have the same key value "ZZ", they are still not sorted alphabetically based on the next field, which is the title. Is there a way to do this too instead of manually sorting them with ZZ1, ZZ2 etc?

Comment: @Dimitris —As a general proposition, if you want to use a field for sorting purposes, the field values must be unique. Thus, if one wishes to make use of the `key` field for sorting purposes, you can’t have duplicate field values.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Therefore I can either copy paste the title field in the key field to sort everything alphabetically, or add a ZZ in front to sort them alphabetically at the end.